# How to execute a service in Global's Session_Start()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

I currently have a asp.net mvc application with ABP implementation. I currently want to execute a service method inside the Session_Start(), may I ask how abouts would I do that.

The service can be executed anywhere I have access to the IOC resolve but I'm in the global file and I'm not entirely sure how to do that from there.

```
protected void Session_Start()
{
    // starting a session and already authenticated means we have an old cookie
    var existingUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;
    if (existingUser != null && existingUser.Identity.Name != "")
    {
        // execute app service here.
        // if I'm exposed to IOCresolver I would do the following below
        var srv = _iocResolver.Resolve<SettingsAppService>();
        srv.UpdateItems();
    }
}
```

May I ask how do I access IOC resolver on global.asax.cs file, if even possible. My goal is to execute the service when the user has re-established his session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation on [Dependency Injection](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dependency-Injection#iiocresolver-iiocmanager-and-iscopediocresolver):

> The IIocResolver (and IIocManager) also have the **CreateScope** extension method (defined in the Abp.Dependency namespace) to safely release all resolved dependencies.
>
> At the end of using block, all resolved dependencies are automatically removed.

> If you are in a static context or can not inject IIocManager, as a last resort, you can use a singleton object **IocManager.Instance** everywhere.

So, use a scope with `IocManager.Instance`:

- `using (var scope = IocManager.Instance.CreateScope()) { ... }`
  → `IocManager.Instance.UsingScope(scope => { ... })`

```
protected void Session_Start()
{
    // Starting a session and already authenticated means we have an old cookie
    var existingUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;
    if (existingUser != null && existingUser.Identity.Name != "")
    {
        IocManager.Instance.UsingScope(scope => // Here
        {
            // Execute app service here.
            var srv = scope.Resolve<SettingsAppService>();
            srv.UpdateItems();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static link to your IoC resolver and use it in Global.asax. You even can add it to Global.asax.cs. Set this property after container registration and use it from anywhere.

```
public static YourIocResolver IocResolver { get; set; }
```